# How can I compute the principal component scores with the same result as returned by prcomp() in $x?

Tags: r

When I try to compute the principal components (PC) scores (i.e., the dataset projected in the PC space), I obtain a different result from what `prcomp()` reports in the `$x` attribute of its result. I center and scale the data.

I run `prcomp()` as

```
pca.result = prcomp(USArrests, scale=TRUE)
```

Then I can access the the wanted PC scores as

```
pca.result$x  # 1
```

From the doc., I understand the above centers and scales the data before multiplying them by the rotation matrix (a.k.a. variable loadings, a.k.a. eigenvectors).
I am trying to reproduce the result above by projecting (rotating) the dataset myself, as in:

```
((as.matrix(USArrests)-pca.result$center)/pca.result$scale) %*% pca.result$rotation  # 2
```

But the result I get from `# 2` is different from the result I get from `# 1`.

How should I correct `# 2` so that it gives the same result as `# 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit simpler. Just use the `score()` function to compute the standardized data:

```
pcscores <- scale(USArrests) %*% pca.result$rotation
```

If you want to use the statistics in `pca.result`:

```
means <- pca.result$center
sdevs <- pca.result$scale
center <- sweep(USArrests, 2, means)
zscores <- sweep(center, 2, sdevs, "/")
pcscores2 <- as.matrix(zscores) %*% pca.result$rotation
```

Your method subtracts means down each column instead of across columns.